# A interesting and easy looking question that involves colouring of the Cartesian plane

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

Take the graph of a $f(x)$ which can be any arbitrary function, e.g. $x^2$ .
We draw tangents to each and every point on it and colour them. If relative to a fixed points have $z$ times the number of tangents passing through it, it is said to be of degree $z$.

The interesting part is that for a general point $S(h,k)$ what is its degree? I think that I should consider easier cases first. Have you a solution/idea that how to solve the problem? (don't uphold or down vote the question will be edited and improved gradually) 
[for example in case of y=x. W.R.T. to (0,0) the degree of all other points is 1 on line; and 0 on others. 
I think that it is related to the multi-valued-ness and interjectivity of $f'(x)$.

Comment: Ask doubts (if any)

Comment: This is not clear.  What does the coloring have to do with anything?  You are just asking how many tangents to the graph pass through a fixed point on the plane, yes?  It's easier if you ask, given a point $P=(a,b)$ in the plane, for how many $x$ does the tangent to the graph at $(x,f(x))$ pass through $P$.  That's just the number of solutions to $f(x)-b=(x-a)\times f'(x)$.  For your question you have to also ask whether some of those tangents may coincide as lines.

Comment: (colouring part was for fun)